# Present ModalViewController from NSObject Class

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, viewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I am asking because didn't find an answer here. I have singleton class that fetching some data from internet. After I fetched the data I need to transfer it to view controller that situated on second place after main view controller and navigation controller.

SingletonClass
     |
     |
NavController->MainViewController->GettingDataViewcontroller (ImagePickerViewController in my case)

I tried at all that I know:

1. This code will present needed controller with blank screen:

`ImagePickerViewController *imgPicker = [[ImagePickerViewController alloc] init];
 UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:imgPicker];
UIViewController *vc  = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] firstObject] rootViewController];
[imgPicker getParsedUrls:self.picturesUrl];
[vc presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];`

1. This code will present view controller with white screen but with no objects (buttons etc) on it:

`UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
ImagePickerViewController *imgPicker = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ImagePicker"];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:imgPicker];
UIViewController *vc  = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] firstObject] rootViewController];
[imgPicker getParsedUrls:self.picturesUrl];
[vc presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];`

In Both ways I am getting slog code I put in second controller That I am getting it.

What I miss here? Thanks for help

Comment: what in your didFinishLaunchingWithOPtion method?

Comment: - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
Basic without changes